# C programs outputting the same number no matter what I change

Tags: c

So I'm having a weird issue where regardless of .c file, compiler, IDE, or what I change my output is the same every time. At first I was writing a simple program for my class,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int n1, n2, res;
    printf("Enter two numbers to divide.\n");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    scanf("%d", &n2);

    res = n1/n2;

    if (n2 == 0) {

        printf("You cannot divide by 0!\n");

    } else {

        printf("Result: %d", &res);
        printf("\n");

    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

And my result always equals the number `6422276`.
I tried creating a new file that simply initializes two integers to `1` and `2` respectively, and tell the compiler to add them together. The output equals `6422276`.

What do I do?

Comment: You're printing the address of `res`, not the value.

Comment: Fred Larson already addressed your main issue. I also suggest you check n2 == 0 before you do the division, otherwise there is not much point to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are printing out the address of your variable

```
printf("Result: %d", &res);
```

To print out the value just do

```
printf("Result: %d", res);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed you would need the "&" as you would with printf.

Comment: That only applies to `scanf()` because it needs to know where to put the data (and that's what the `&` gives you)

Answer (score 1):

Dont use & :

```
printf("Result: %d", &res);
```

Write:

```
printf("Result: %d", res);
```

Answer (score 0):

As other people say do you are printing the address.

However there is also another error: you should check the denominator is not 0 before the division otherwise it does not make any sense.

## include

int main () {

```
int n1, n2, res;
printf("Enter two numbers to divide.\n");
scanf("%d", &n1);
scanf("%d", &n2);

if (n2 == 0) {

    printf("You cannot divide by 0!\n");

} else {
    res = n1/n2;
    printf("Result: %d", res);
    printf("\n");

}

system("PAUSE");
```

}